# mod_rewrite works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

AS the title says, my rewrite rules does not work when I upload it to  my server (Ubuntu LTS). The .htaccess-file is in play, but does nothing.

mod_rewrite is loaded, I've verified that several ways. I tried writing rubbish text in the .htaccess file and got a 500 internal error, so the file seems to be in the loop. The virtualHost configuration has "allowOverride All".

The .htaccess file consists of a series of rewrite rules, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^webshop$ index.php?page=webshop [QSA]

RewriteRule ^webshop/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=webshop&catID=$1 [QSA]
```

On the server I have to virtualhosts, one public server and one testing server. The public server works fine, all rewriterules are similar to above and works. It's the virtualhost for testing that doesn't want to play. One server, one IP, two FQDNs.

Ideas?

EDIT - Here's the VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin beta@example.com
        ServerName beta.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/www-root
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/beta/www-root>
                AddDefaultCharset utf-8
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from (Two IPs omitted)
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/temp>
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.beta.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's because your rule `webshop/([0-9]+)` generates a virtual folder and you forward it to `index.php` in current folder. To solve your problem, use this rule: `RewriteRule ^webshop/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=webshop&catID=$1 [L]`. The leading slash means `begin from root`. This way, you forward it to `index.php` which is in root folder, not in your virtual folder

Comment: Check out your Serverconfiguration - On your server must **AllowOverride All** set (see `http.conf` or on your `VirtualHost`)!

Comment: Can you post the VirtualHost?

Comment: @JustinIurman Thanks, no change though.

Comment: Since you seem to have full access to the server – enable rewrite logging, then you’ll be able to see what goes wrong and where.

Comment: put "RewriteBase /" above "RewriteRule" line

Comment: @alreadycoded.com: RewriteBase made no difference

Comment: @CBroe: Got absolutely nothing in the log file. It creates the log file, but it is zero bytes all the time.

Comment: I've discovered something: rewrite works - but not when there is a folder with the same name as (a part of) the regex in the .htaccess file. I have a folder kalled "webshop", so the regex in the question fails. If I rename the folder (or the regex) - it works.

Comment: Then try deactivating `MultiViews` (via `Options` directive) – that often interferes in cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there is a folder with the same name as (a part of) the regex. I have a file called "webshop.php", and for some reason the regex `^webshop$` then fails (servers seems to prefer the actual folder/files rather than a local rewrite).

Comment: You should have said it in your question. The solution is to add this code before `RewriteEngine on`: `Options -MultiViews`