# mod_rewrite URI with same name as folder or files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A simple .htaccess file with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^webshop$ /index.php?page=webshop [L]
```

... does not work for me because a have a file called webshop.php in the web root. Renaming the file solves the poblem, and changing the regex in the .htaccess file solves the problem, but still - it's only a partial match of the file name...? The only thing I can find on this is to use

> DirectorySlash off

I've tried that and it made no difference.

Need some help here, there must be a pretty simple solution to this.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? What is wrong and what it should be like?

Comment: Duplicate of [mod\_rewrite works on localhost but not on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348428/mod-rewrite-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-server) – yes, that the existing folder with the same name seems to be part of the problem wasn’t in your original question, but you have stated it there already, so no need for a new question on the same problem.

Comment: The problem is that I want my rewrite to work, regardless of folder and file names. @CBroe: Old problem "solved" (sort of), the way I see it, it made more sense starting a new thread where the problem could be clearly defined.

Comment: i lost a few hours on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have `MultiViews` options enabled. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Disable it by placing this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Yes, it fixed the problem. I was getting 404 error when the a file of the same name than the rewrite existed. (apache wasn't even "calling" the file)